# Enable In-app purchase feature in already published app

Tags: android

I have an android app in play store, is it possible to enable in-app purchase feature in it? How is it possible? please add your valuable comments

Comment: enable? did you code for it?

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible with existing code. You have to upload new apk to play store in which you have to code. I would suggest to use Firebase Remote config feature to enable or disable any feature in your app.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to add inapp products to an app, but only in a new app version.

You have to put up a version of your app on the store with `<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />` added to your manifest file.

After that, you'll be able to create in-app products from the 'Store presence' -> 'In-app products' tab in the developer console. From there you can go about implementing everything in your next app version

Side note, I've been using this library in a couple of apps for in app billing. Has been much easier than implementing fully myself -> https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3

Answer (score 0):

Yes! Use the new [Play Billing Library](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library.html) to add support in your project.

---

Of course, you will need to publish a new version of your app to the store.